# How to make main thread waiting for goroutine execution?

Tags: go, asynchronous, channel

I am trying to understand what the go keyword really does when calling a method. I understand that putting go keyword before a method will trigger Go to execute this function on a goroutine, which can be on the same processor or different processor.

But when I practiced with the following code, I was confused by cases that didn't return the expected outputs which are "start at $some-time-stamp" and "get message : $some-time-stamp".

More specific question descriptions are in the code comments. Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    message := make(chan string, 1)
// I am aware of if I make a channel this way, it's asynchronous non-blocking

    workOnWriteOnlyChannel(message)
    workOnReadOnlyChannel(message)
    /*
        start at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
        get message : done at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
    */
// the above one worked as expected, is because it runs synchronously, no blocking is happening

    go workOnWriteOnlyChannel(message)
    workOnReadOnlyChannel(message)
    /*
        start at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
        get message : done at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
    */
// main thread executes to create a goroutine(let's call it goroutine-2) which is responsible to execute method 
// workOnWriteOnlyChannel, then the main thread goes to the next line immediately
// main thread executes method workOnReadOnlyChannel, and main thread will block for 5 seconds because goroutine-2 won't update the shared channel until 5 seconds after
// so after 5 seconds, the main thread will unblock

    workOnWriteOnlyChannel(message)
    go workOnReadOnlyChannel(message)
    /*
        start at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
    */
// I thought after calling workOnWriteOnlyChannel, the shared channel has value, though the 
// method workOnReadOnlyChannel is executed by another goroutine, it should be two outputs, 
// but it didn't which confuses me

    go workOnReadOnlyChannel(message)
    workOnWriteOnlyChannel(message)
    /*
        start at 2009-11-10 23:00:05 +0000 UTC m=+5.000000001
    */
// I thought a new goroutine(let's call it goroutine-1) will execute method 
// workOnReadOnlyChannel, but at first 5 seconds, it will be blocked, 
// but the main thread is not blocked, and when the main thread goes to execute method 
// workOnWriteOnlyChannel, the channel will have one element, and goroutine-1 will unblock, 
// but it didn't which confuses me

    /*
    workOnReadOnlyChannel(message)
    go workOnWriteOnlyChannel(message)
    */
    // fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
// I think I know this one, correct me if I'm wrong
// main thread will block when it goes to execute method workOnReadOnlyChannel, 
// so can't go to the next line, 
// so deadlock happens
}

func workOnWriteOnlyChannel(messages chan<- string) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    messages<- "done"
    defer fmt.Printf("start at %s\n", time.Now())
}

func workOnReadOnlyChannel(messages <-chan string) {
    fmt.Printf("get message : %s at %s\n", <-messages, time.Now())
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that main function ( or any other function ) waits for the goroutines, so in your cases, the main function ( and the program ) ends before your `workOnReadOnlyChannel ` starts, and you don't see the "get message . . . ". Use sync.mutex or other synchronization solutions to overcome this issue.

Comment: by the outputs, it looks that you comment on all but one pair of functions before running this. If so the pairs 3 and 4, where you don't see the "done", is because you're not waiting for them to receive from the channel (since it's buffered) and then printing. This requires a certain amount of time and your main function exits first (main doesn't wait for you goroutines to finish)

Comment: The go keyword starts a new goroutine..

Comment: Have a look at WaitGroups, here's a simple example: https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1

Comment: @meshkati Oh I see, I recalled that sync.Mutex and sync.RWMutex is used when I read some code snippets. It makes sense to me now. Thx

Comment: @hmoragrega Yeah, adding a time.Sleep(time.Second) after pair 3 and 4, I can get the expected outputs.Thx. https://play.golang.org/p/rC09wnxsfjh

Comment: @Rob I found WaitGroup is also from sync, that's new to me, good to know it, thx.

Comment: @meshkati I think sync.Mutex isn't applicable to my case. It's a lock. It didn't guarantee main thread waits for goroutine(s) to finish.

Comment: @new-user sorry you are right, I ment `sync.WaitGroup`

Answer (score 0):

I just put applicable comments together so I can close the question. (TBH I think the previous title of my question is really bad, it didn't convey the meaning of my real question. After changing to the current one, it still doesn't feel right, but it's better. I think this title can come across by people with the same confusion in the future.)

The main thread doesn't wait for goroutines to finish. It's the answer to my very first confusion.

As for how to make the main thread wait for goroutines:

Solution 1, force the main thread to sleep for a bit, so goroutine returns before the main thread finished;

Solution 2, use sync.WaitGroup to wait for goroutines to finish(its usage is similar to CountDownLatch)